# Source code description in LaTeX

Tags: java, printing

I have a problem concerning the creation of the name below a "Source code" (Listing) in LaTeX. When I have a figure I use:

```
       \begin{figure}[t]
       \centering
       \includegraphics{Figures/drawing.pdf}
       \caption{Spoken Dialogue System}

       \label{fig:SLDS2}
       \end{figure}
```

I see

```
Figure 4.5.: Spoken Dialog System
```

on the screen.
However, when I could not figure out how to print

```
Listing.4.5 Java Code
```

below this framed code on the screen. What should I add to this code? The source code is as shown in the following:

```
     \begin{framed}
     \begin{lstlisting}[frame=single, backgroundcolor=\color{light-gray}, basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily, language=Java, numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny             
     \color{black}]

          [HERE IS THE JAVA CODE]

  \end{lstlisting}

  \end{framed}
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Before you copy-paste the question, though, call over some moderator help to see if you can get this migrated.  Or, search over there first and see if your question's been answered.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from another Stack Exchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 13):

You can use the `caption=<caption text>` option for `lstlisting`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\colorlet{light-gray}{gray!20}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single, backgroundcolor=\color{light-gray}, basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily, language=Java, numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny\color{black},caption= {A desciption of the listing}]
[HERE IS THE JAVA CODE]
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Since you didn't provide your definition for `light-gray` I used a temporary one in my example.

Initially I overlooked the requirement about the caption position to be on the bottom; this can be a chieved using the `captionpos=b` option (although for listings I would suggest to have the caption on top, as in the default settings):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\colorlet{light-gray}{gray!20}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single, backgroundcolor=\color{light-gray}, basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily, language=Java, numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny\color{black},caption= {A desciption of the listing},captionpos=b]
[HERE IS THE JAVA CODE]
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If the same settings are going to be used for various listings, it's better to use `\lstset` instead of having to repeat them for each `lstlisting` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\colorlet{light-gray}{gray!20}

\lstset{
  frame=single,
  backgroundcolor=\color{light-gray},
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
  language=Java, 
  numbers=left, 
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{black},
  captionpos=b
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[,caption= {A desciption of the listing}]
[HERE IS THE JAVA CODE]
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```